# add one year to datetime with php

Tags: php

```
$data['user']['time'] = '2011-03-07 00:33:45';
```

how can we add 1 year to this date ?

something like `$newdata = $data['user']['time'] + 1 year` ?

or

```
$newdata = 2012-03-07 00:33:45
```

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: What is `$data['user']['time']`? A string?

Comment: it should be a date time mysql format. sori edited

Comment: possible duplicate of [date minus 1 year?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year) and every other of the hundreds of existing questions asking "how to [add/substract] x [s/m/h/d/m/y] to a date".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) is the function you're looking for:

```
$data['user']['seal_data'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($data['user']['time'])));
```

Comment: Yeah it returns UNIX timestamps. You'll need to use something like date() to reformat it.

Answer (score 12):

First, you have to convert the MySQL `datetime` to something that PHP can understand. There are two ways of doing this...

1. Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in your query to tell MySQL to return a UNIX timestamp of the `datetime` column.

   ```
   SELECT whatever, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTime) AS 'myUnixTime' FROM myTable;
   ```
2. Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to convert your string time to something PHP can understand.

   ```
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['user']['time']);
   ```

---

Once that is done, you can work with the time... Depending on the method you used above, you can use one of the following.

1. If you have a unix timestamp, you can use the following to add a year:

   ```
   $inAYear = strtotime('+1 year', $data['user']['unixTime']);
   ```
2. If you have a `DateTime` object, you can use the following:

   ```
   $inAYear = $date->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
   ```

---

Now, to display your date in a format that is respectable, you must tell PHP to return a string in the proper format.

1. If you have a unix timestamp, you can use the following:

   ```
   $strTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inAYear);
   ```
2. If you have a `DateTime` object, you can use the following:

   ```
   $strTime = $inAYear->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   ```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with all of that, you can simply add one year when you query.

```
SELECT whatever, DATE_ADD(myTime, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS 'inAYear' FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 8):

## Current (2017) Practice is to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

This question is top on a google search for "php datetime add one year", but *severely outdated*. While most of the previous answers will work fine for most cases, the established standard is to use **DateTime** objects for this instead, primarily due `strtotime` requiring careful manipulation of timezones and DST.

#### TL;DR

1. Convert to **DateTime**: `$date = new DateTime('2011-03-07 00:33:45', [user TZ]);`
2. Use [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php): `$date->modify('+1 year');`
3. Format to needs.

   - Change the timezone with [DateTime::setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) from the [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php): `$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));`
   - Convert to string with [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php): `echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Following this pattern for manipulating dates and times will handle the worst oddities of timezone/DST/leap-time for you.

Just remember two final notes:

- Life is easier with your system timezone set at ***UTC***.
- NEVER modify the system timezone outside of configuration files.

  - I've seen too much code that relies on [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). If you're doing this, stop. Save the timezone in a variable, and pass it around your application instead, *please*.

## More Reading

[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

[Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy/2487938#2487938)

[PHP - strtotime, specify timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569014/php-strtotime-specify-timezone)

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to do this pretty easily. Something like:

```
$newdata = date('c', strtotime($data['user']['time'] . ' +1 year'));
```

Though the 'c' format string isn't the same as your input format. You could consult [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)'s docs for how to construct the correct one.

'Y-m-d H:i:s' — as Tim Cooper suggests — looks correct.

Comment: `$newdata = $data['user']['time'] + strtotime("+1 year");` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (not tested).

```
$data = "2011-03-07 00:33:45";

echo 'Original date +1 year: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data)) . " +1 year"));
```

Comment: You seem a little confused with your quotes but this works, simple so have a vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First-of-all if your date format is separated by a slash (/), like **'2019/12/31'** then you should convert it in dash (-) format, like '**2019-12-31**', to do so use `str_replace()` function.

```
$string = str_replace('/', '-', '2019/12/31'); //output: 2019-12-31
```

To add time/day/month/year do not use `strtotime()` function, because it can't add a time which is beyond year ***2038***.
So here I would prefer to use `DateTime()` function.

```
$string = '2000-01-01';
$date = new DateTime($string);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P60Y5M2DT6H3M25S')); //60 Years 5 Months 2 Days 6 Hours 3 Minutes 25 Seconds
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //output: 2060-06-03 06:03:25
```