# PHP DateTime, paid date + a year term

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add one year to datetime with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212240/add-one-year-to-datetime-with-php)

Paid Date: `2012-10-19 13:13:20`

Term: `3` (three years)

I need to turn these two values into a `DateTime` that I can then compare to todays date and find out if the subscription is coming up for renewal.

Not sure how to properly accomplish this...

I've tried:

```
$term = $row['term'];   
$paid = $row['paid_date'];

$renew = strtotime("+$term years", $paid);
$today = strtotime('now');
```

But apparently in this situation, all dates are less than ...

Comment: Whoever voted this down is a complete waste of breath. Thanks for helping out ...

Comment: I find it funny that your first try was multiplying by `$term` (I didn't downvote you)

Comment: Yeah, it's hilarious. I didn't actually attempt that ... it's just an example of what I need to accomplish

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212240/add-one-year-to-datetime-with-php answer 2, -1 for not even attempting to google

Comment: Steve ... I'm looking through PHP.net right now and there are so many different ways of potentially doing this. And that's not the result I need.

Comment: @dcolumbus Given that there's no actual question, this is perfectly worth a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the paid date as a string:

```
if(strtotime("2012-10-19 13:13:20 +3 years") > time()) {
     // expired
}
```

If you have paid date as a timestamp:

```
if(strtotime("+3 years", $paidDate) > time()) {
     // expired
}
```

Comment: Assume that paid_date is MySQL datetime and term is integer, it is sufficient to use `strtotime("{$row['paid_date']} +{$row['term']} years")`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for helping me out, Salman.

Answer (score 0):

turn the date into a timestamp and compare it with todays timestamp; if the difference is more than 3 years in seconds the subscription is running out.

Answer (score 0):

Convert paid + 3 years and today into unix timestmps, if the renewal date is less than today, the subscription has expired.

```
$renew = strtotime('+'. $term .' years', $paid);
$today = strtotime('now');

If ($renew < $today) 
{
  //subscription has run out
}
```

Assumes $term is an integer from a database and $paid is a datetime from a MySQL database converted to a unix timestamp (select unix_timestamp(paid) as paid from paidtable).