# PHP date add 5 year to current date

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
$end=date('Y-m-d');
```

I use it to get the current date, and I need the date 5 years in the future, something like:

```
$end=date('(Y + 5)-m-d');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add one year to datetime with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212240/add-one-year-to-datetime-with-php)

Comment: Gets slightly quirky on 29th February in a leap year when you suddenly get 1st March - be aware of such oddities when trying to manipulate dates

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Try with:

```
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 years'));
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use this example to add 1 year to a date, but I already have variables: `$invoicedate = $_POST['invdate']; $invdate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime($invoicedate));` so would I then add a 3rd line `$due = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invdate,'+1 year'));`?

Comment: what if its 2.5 yrs date

Comment: @Sayuj3: Use months instead of years. 2.5 years is 30 months.

Answer (score 29):

**Modifying dates** [based on this post](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/working-with-date-and-time-in-php/) 
 
strtotime() is really powerful and allows you to modify/transform dates easily with it’s relative expressions too:

**Procedural**

```
    $dateString = '2011-05-01 09:22:34';
    $t = strtotime($dateString);
    $t2 = strtotime('-3 days', $t);
    echo date('r', $t2) . PHP_EOL; // returns: Thu, 28 Apr 2011 09:22:34 +0100
```

**DateTime**

```
    $dateString = '2011-05-01 09:22:34';
    $dt = new DateTime($dateString);
    $dt->modify('-3 days');
    echo $dt->format('r') . PHP_EOL; // returns: Thu, 28 Apr 2011 09:22:34 +0100
```

The stuff you can throw at strtotime() is quite surprising and very human readable. Have a look at this example looking for Tuesday next week.

**Procedural**

```
    $t = strtotime("Tuesday next week");
    echo date('r', $t) . PHP_EOL; // returns: Tue, 10 May 2011 00:00:00 +0100
```

**DateTime**

```
    $dt = new DateTime("Tuesday next week");
    echo $dt->format('r') . PHP_EOL; // returns: Tue, 10 May 2011 00:00:00 +0100
```

Note that these examples above are being returned relative to the time now.
The full list of time formats that strtotime() and the DateTime constructor takes are listed on the [PHP Supported Date and Time Formats page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).

**Another example, suitable for your case could be:** [based on this post](http://www.phpjabbers.com/date-and-time-manipulations-with-php-php30.html)

```
    <?php
    //How to get the day 3 days from now:
    $today = date("j");
    $thisMonth = date("n");
    $thisYear = date("Y");
    echo date("F j Y", mktime(0,0,0, $thisMonth, $today+3, $thisYear)); 

    //1 week from now:
    list($today,$thisMonth,$thisYear) = explode(" ", date("j n Y"));
    echo date("F j Y", mktime(0,0,0, $thisMonth, $today+7, $thisYear));

    //4 months from now:
    list($today,$thisMonth,$thisYear) = explode(" ", date("j n Y"));
    echo date("F j Y", mktime(0,0,0, $thisMonth+4, $today, $thisYear)); 

    //3 years, 2 months and 35 days from now:
    list($today,$thisMonth,$thisYear) = explode(" ", date("j n Y"));
    echo date("F j Y", mktime(0,0,0, $thisMonth+2, $today+35, $thisYear+3));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 14):

Use this code to add years or months or days or hours or minutes or seconds to a given date

```
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 years", strtotime('2014-05-22 10:35:10'))); //2015-05-22 10:35:10
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 months", strtotime('2014-05-22 10:35:10')));//2014-06-22 10:35:10
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 days", strtotime('2014-05-22 10:35:10')));//2014-05-23 10:35:10
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hours", strtotime('2014-05-22 10:35:10')));//2014-05-22 11:35:10
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 minutes", strtotime('2014-05-22 10:35:10')));//2014-05-22 10:36:10
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 seconds", strtotime('2014-05-22 10:35:10')));//2014-05-22 10:35:11
```

You can also subtract replacing + to -

Answer (score 8):

```
$date = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
$newdate = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("+1 year",$date));
```

Answer (score 7):

Its very very easy with Carbon.

```
$date = "2016-02-16"; // Or Your date
$newDate    = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->addYear(1);
```

Comment: Carbon class and its methods belongs to a particular frame work (Laravel) and in the question asked we do not find any frame work name rather it is asked using PHP date functions. I think that's why you didn't get any up thumbs :)

Comment: Actually carbon is not dependent on particular framework. Anyone can pull in carbon via composer and use it. It is a easier way to deal with the issue if one does not wishes to check core PHP's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon):

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->addYears(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add one year to todays date use the following:

```
$oneYearOn = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", mktime()) . " + 365 day"));
```

Comment: This was great thank you very much :)
i'm accepting a few moments later

Comment: @Letter Look at my answer - it's much simplier.

Answer (score 1):

You may use DateInterval for this purpose;

```
$currentDate = new \DateTime(); //creates today timestamp
$currentDate->add(new \DateInterval('P5Y')); //this means 5 Years
and you can now format it;
$currentDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$current_date=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

echo $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 years',$current_date));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
$presentyear = '2013-08-16 12:00:00';

$nextyear  = date("M d,Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",strtotime($presentyear )),   date("d",strtotime($presentyear )),   date("Y",strtotime($presentyear ))+5));

echo $nextyear;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$yearnow= date("Y");
$yearnext=$yearnow+1;
echo date("Y")."-".$yearnext;
```

Comment: Not quite what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and add next Days, Months and Years

```
// current month: Aug 2018
$n = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++){
   $d = strtotime("$i days");
   $x = strtotime("$i month");
   $y = strtotime("$i year");
   echo "Dates : ".$dates = date('d M Y', "+$d days");
   echo "<br>";
   echo "Months : ".$months = date('M Y', "+$x months");
   echo '<br>';
   echo "Years : ".$years = date('Y', "+$y years");
   echo '<br>';
}
```