# Add +1 year with data already saved using php

Tags: php

i have db with date format like this : `28 - 04 - 2015`

how to add that data +1 year with php?

any idea?

Thanks very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269556/php-date-add-1-year-to-current-date

Comment: Your date seems to have blank spaces on the left and right of the hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo date('d - m - Y', strtotime('+1 years', strtotime(str_replace(" ", "",$DateFromDB))));
```

EDIT: Sorry wrong format

Working example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/148e670733af48fdde6fc37884550744defb6eca

Comment: how  to add +1 year using my data?
Eg. : `28 - 04 - 2015` using php and be `28 - 04 - 2016`
is it possible?

Comment: @Andreas, imagine the date is stored in a variable, how would you include the variable in your answser?

Comment: Sorry forgot that.. :) just a sec

Comment: @JaparS , Jose , Updated

Comment: Missing the last parenthesis!

Comment: not work...i already try :(

Comment: @JaparS, it works, maybe because of the spaces in your date.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez correct with str_replace(" ", "",$date) it works

Comment: Working! Many thanks!

Comment: @JaparS No problem! It was tougher than at firts glance. Just accept the answer and I'm happy :-)

Comment: @JaparS Ok you were qicker than me

Answer (score 0):

```
date('d - m - Y', strtotime($date . ' +1 years'));
```

Comment: There is a period after `$date`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update database using INTERVAL

```
UPDATE table SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you save the value of your date in the variable named `$date`:

```
$date = '28 - 04 - 2015';
$date = strtotime(str_replace(' ', '', $date)); // Remove the spaces from your date and convert it into a time
$date = strtotime('+1 years', $date); // Add one year to the result
echo date('m - d - Y', $date); // Print the date 1 year later in the same format you had originally
```

The result would be:

```
28 - 04 - 2016
```

If you want it in one line:

```
$date = strtotime('+1 years', strtotime(str_replace(' ', '', $date)));
```