# Date time convert is incorrectly being modified

Tags: php, datetime

I am having issues getting my code to return the correct response.

```
$Birthd = '06-27-1996';

$NewISSdate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime(date("m-d-Y", strtotime($Birthd)) . " +21 years"));
```

When I run this the response is: `"12-31-1969"`

I believe this is a default date of sorts, but what can I do to repair my code? If ran with a different `$Birthd` string such as `"07-03-1996".`

Comment: Please change - to / and try with your code

Comment: And 0 is 1970/01/01 so 31st of December is 0 epoch with timezone correction - also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269556/php-date-add-1-year-to-current-date

Comment: Still having the issue after changing to "/" unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change string date format and then add years to it like below:-

```
$Birthd = '06-27-1996';
$Birthd = str_replace("-","/",$Birthd);

echo $NewISSdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Birthd)) . " + 21 years"));
```

Output:-https://eval.in/835509  OR  https://eval.in/835555

Reference:- [php different acceptable date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think Im in love. You saved my life. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanReddings  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Change - to / and try...

```
$Birthd = '06/27/1996';

$NewISSdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($Birthd)) . " +21 years"));
```

Comment: try with this `date("m/d/Y",strtotime('+21 years', strtotime($Birthd)));`