# How can I add date to 1 year. in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue with this statement can some one help

```
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($vehicle->created_at)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($vehicle->created_at), " +1 year") }}</td>
```

Comment: even with . " +1 year" does not add one year

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269556/php-date-add-1-year-to-current-date/18269603

Comment: try `date('d F Y' , strtotime(strtotime($vehicle->created_at), '+1 years')` or `date('d F Y' , strtotime(strtotime($vehicle->created_at), '+1 year')`

Comment: Which kind of "issue" do you have? That does not look like valid PHP code after all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel automatically wrap `created_at` to `Carbon` instance, and Carbon instance you can easly add year using `addYear()` function. See Documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub,

Corrected code is

```
date('d F Y', strtotime($vehicle->created_at->addYear()))
```

for more good practice you can use as **@Rafael** suggested this code for get same result

```
<td>{{ $vehicle->created_at->format('d F Y') }}</td>
<td>{{ $vehicle->created_at->addYear()->format('d F Y') }}</td>
```

Comment: @InforootIhalili are you try my answer??

Comment: Thanks a lot Davit

Comment: Make it simpler :)
$vehicle->created_at->addYear()->format('d F Y');

Comment: @Rafael you right I am update my answer according your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

`+1 year` should concat with `$vehicle->created_at` instead of passing as third parameter to `date` function.
**Code:**

```
date('d F Y', strtotime($vehicle->created_at . " +1 year") );
```