# PHP How to min or plus year with timespan

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna ask, how to min or plus a year in php
I have a date like this 1992-09-10
then I'm using timespan (codeigniter library) to knowing, how long the date is,

here's the code

```
$time = '1992-09-10';
$timeago = timespan(strtotime($time));

echo $timeago;
```

then the result is

```
24 Years, 1 Month, 3 Weeks, 2 Days, 23 Hours, 51 Minutes
```

and I want to decrease (-5) years
the result should be

```
19 Years, 1 Month, 3 Weeks, 2 Days, 23 Hours, 51 Minutes
```

my code is

```
$time = '1992-09-10';
$timeago = timespan(strtotime('-5 years', strtotime($time)));

echo $timeago;
```

but the result is

```
29 Years, 1 Month, 3 Weeks, 3 Days, 17 Hours, 54 Minutes
```

anyone know to make it?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: timespan is a personal function you have created ? Does it take in paramater only string like this "YYYY-MM-DD" ?

Comment: oh, I'm using codeigniter, I'm using helper date

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212240/add-one-year-to-datetime-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you get is perfectly normal : `1992 - 5 years` equals `1987`, which is indeed 29 years ago.

Just use `+5 years` instead :

```
$time = '1992-09-10';
$timeago = timespan(strtotime('+5 years', strtotime($time)));

echo $timeago;
// 19 Years, 1 Month, 4 Weeks, 1 Day, 38 Minutes
```

Comment: @yuliantosaparudin You could also reverse the order of your parameters in the `timespan` function :  `$timeago = timespan(strtotime($time), strtotime('-5 years'));`

Comment: Haha, no problem. Keep in mind that the results might be slightly different though, as there might not be the same number of leap years between `1992` and `2011` than between `1997` and `2016`.