# Is the result of strtotime() changed based on the timezone?

Tags: php

I used `strtotime($datetime)` in PHP to convert textual datetime description into Unix timestamp (see code below).

```
$datetime = '2012-04-17 00:00:00';
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
```

However, the result of `$timestamp` in Time zone (**London**) was **1334617200** and in Time zone (**Beijing**) it was **1334620800**.

Can anyone explain me why this happened? Is the result of `strtotime()` changed based on the timezone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1 It's very clear in the documentation

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation:

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a
>   time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use
>   different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See
>   date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default
>   time zone.

So yes, it is based on the time zone unless you specify a specific timezone in `$datetime`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.  Timezone is taken into account.

See also:  [PHP - strtotime, specify timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3569014/362536)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default timezone with: date_default_timezone_set, otherwise the default system time zone is used.

Reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Answer (score 0):

To use GMT, use [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) as the second parameter:

```
strtotime($datetime, time())
```