# Inserting a date in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to insert a date into a collection.
I use the class `MongoDate` to create the date object:

```
$today = new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')));
```

The problem is that once it is in my collection the date is 2 hours earlier.

For instance, `$today` here should be `2013-05-28 00:00:00` but once in the database it is `2013-05-27 22:00:00`.

I can't resolve this problem by adding 2 hours manually to the timestamp because I use the date in queries.

The local time of the server where Mongo is running is set to the correct time of my country.

Comment: what wrong with saving a date as `new Date` object? it will include timezone data

Comment: All dates in MongoDB are UTC, why cant you make your application timezone aware?

Comment: I use the dates as range in my queries with $gte and $lte operators. This is why I want to use the MongoDate format which allows comparison and is easily readable (timestamps are not). I need to find a way to insert a date independently of my timezone and the summer / winter hour change because this will cause problems.

Comment: My PHP is quite rusty, but maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569014/php-strtotime-specify-timezone

Comment: @Sagish: two reasons why it's _wrong_, so to speak. 1) if your code is that of an importer/updater tool, let's say from CSV datan, so, string, you want the insert/update method to implicitly cast the date to a MongoDB date data type. And 2) Date object would bear timezone data, but you only want to store dates all in UTC offset in MongoDB, and leave the renderer to present dates in local offset.

Answer (score 21):

That works in the new php version of mongodb:

```
new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime((new DateTime($today))->getTimestamp()*1000)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

```
$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
$today = new MongoDate($ts);
```

This is working.

Answer (score 2):

Remove old document and insert

```
        $bill = array(  
                "_id" => 1, 
                "name" => "A", 
                "lastModified" => new MongoDate()
            );

        $collection->insert($bill);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: If you need date created for your object model.

```
$date_created = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(time()*1000);
```