# PHP MongoDate toDateTime default timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, mongodate

When I create new DateTime object, it has timezone from "date.timezone" setting:

```
print_r(new DateTime());


DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-03-02 03:19:50.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Moscow
)
```

But when I get DateTime object from MongoDate, it has UTC timezone:

```
print_r((new MongoDate()) -> toDateTime())


DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-03-02 00:19:50.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

How can I setup MongoDate to create DateTime objects with my default timezone?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16794508/4385913)

Comment: @Skizo, this is not answer to my question. This answer is about creating MongoDate object, but my question is about getting DateTime from MongoTIme

Answer (score 0):

A way from do this:

```
    $mongoDate = new \MongoDate();
    $dateTimeDefaultTimeZone = $mongoDate->toDateTime()->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()))
```

You will can get the DateTime with default TimeZone.